# Dynamically using testdata based on env in karate framework

Tags: karate

I have test data based on environments. Need to use respecitive environment test data for webservice testing in karate framework.
So I have config file which load variable based on environment. I have edited my feature file as runtime variable to get the path accordingly something like below. It looks I am missing something or might not using right way.

I have kept testdata based on environment in my folders as like below

```
TestData
  |->DEV
      |-> applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json
  |->SIT
      |-> applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json
  |->UAT
      |-> applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json
  |->PROD
      |-> applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json
```

Please help me on this how to pick data based on environment.

Config file

```
dev: {
      baseUrl: 'https://applicationsit.company.com',
      TestData : 'TestData/DEV'
     },
sit: {
    baseUrl: 'https://applicationsit.company.com',
    TestData : 'TestData/SIT'
    },
uat: {
    baseUrl: 'https://applicationuat2.company.com',
    TestData : 'TestData/UAT'
    },
prod: {
    baseUrl: 'https://applicationnewprod.company.com',
    TestData : 'TestData/PROD'
    }
```

Feature file

```
Background:
    * def testdata = TestData
      
@smoke @prod
Scenario: This is success scenario
    Given url baseUrl
    Given path '/cryptoService'
    And request read('#(testdata)/applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json')
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * def encryptedPayload = response
```

Error found in karate

```
And request read('#(testdata)/applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json') 
js failed: 
>>>> 
01: read('#(testdata)/applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json') 
<<<< 
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/workspace/application-prod-test/Continous_Testing/KarateConfigDir/#(testdata)/applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json (No such file or directory) 
- com.intuit.karate.resource.FileResource.getStream(FileResource.java:98) 
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:99) 
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsString(ScenarioFileReader.java:95) 
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:53) 
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:124) 
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'#(var)'` system works only for JSON: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Karate syntax is mostly JS and variables just work normally. With that in mind please make this change:

```
And request read(testdata + '/applicationFeature_scenorio1_Req.json')
```